# Remove all rows that doesn't match a set of strings and recategorization of the columns

Tags: r, text-mining, data-cleaning

I have a set of social media data queried from twitter API, which also included people's self-reported location. However, the location string does not default to a standard format for categorization, and sometimes there are "trolls" value. Here is an example

```
a1 = data.frame(x=c(1:4),y=c("181 Metro Drive San Francisco", "Wall Street New York", "Austin, TX", "The Moon"))
a1
```

My plan is to obtain a CSV file with all cities names around the world at https://www.kaggle.com/max-mind/world-cities-database and import it into R as a vector, here is a small example

```
a2 = c("New York", "Washington", "Austin")
a2
```

What I want to do is to write an R function that cross-references a1 based on a2, replace all strings in a1 where it doesn't appear on a2 as NA, and replace all strings where it appears on a2 by that exact string values. For example, say that our function is f, the output of the function would be as follow

```
x = data.frame(x=c(1:4),c("San Francisco", "New York", "Austin", NA))
x
```

Can I write a function in R for this, or are there any existing R package build for this task? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

We can paste all the city names as a pattern and then use `str_extract` to extract it.

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(a1, str_c(a2, collapse = "|"))
#[1] "San Francisco" "New York"      "Austin"        NA
```

**data**

```
a2 = c("New York", "Washington", "Austin", "San Francisco")
a1 = c("181 Metro Drive San Francisco", "Wall Street New York", 
       "Austin, TX", "The Moon")
```